# Select array elements with variable index bounds in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This might be not possible as the intermediate array would have variable length rows.
What I am trying to accomplish is assigning a value to an array for the elements which have ad index delimited by my array of bounds. As an example:

```
bounds = np.array([[1,2], [1,3], [1,4]])
array = np.zeros((3,4))
__assign(array, bounds, 1)
```

after the assignment should result in

```
array = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

I have tried something like this in various iterations without success:

```
ind = np.arange(array.shape[0])
array[ind, bounds[ind][0]:bounds[ind][1]] = 1
```

I am trying to avoid loops as this function will be called a lot. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check my updated solution. I have added an extremely fast method to my answer if you are ok with a for-loop. If not, please check my second last solution as well which is vectorised, but slightly slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means a Numpy expert, but from the different array [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing) options I could find, this was the fastest solution I could figure out:

```
bounds = np.array([[1,2], [1,3], [1,4]])
array = np.zeros((3,4))
for i, x in enumerate(bounds):
    cols = slice(x[0], x[1]) 
    array[i, cols] = 1
```

Here we iterate through the list of bounds and reference the columns using slices.

I tried the below way of first constructing a list of column indices and a list of row indices, but it was way slower. Like 10 seconds plus vir 0.04 seconds on my laptop for a 10 000 x 10 000 array. I guess the slices make a huge difference.

```
bounds = np.array([[1,2], [1,3], [1,4]])
array = np.zeros((3,4))
cols = []
rows = []
for i, x in enumerate(bounds):
    cols += list(range(x[0], x[1])) 
    rows += (x[1] - x[0]) * [i]

# print(cols) [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
# print(rows) [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

array[rows, cols] = 1
```

Comment: OP has asked for a method without loops.

Comment: as a temporary solution I implemented exactly a loop with slices. I am running this code through a non linear regression algorithm with large arrays (images) so I expect it to have quite an impact, but I could not come up with a better solution.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal he did not. He only said he's *trying* to avoid it.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, i am not saying your solution is wrong, i am saying its incomplete. So is my answer.

Comment: Thanks @DMalan for the work on this. I will leave the question open, in case someone finds a way to do this without a loop.

Comment: Check my solution without any explicit for loops. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Using slices does shave about 30% of the time compared to what I had
    'ind = np.arange(tsize[0])
    for i in ind:
            timg[i, bounds[i][0]:bounds[i][1]] = 1` 
The solution with zip from Akshay is just a tad slower so I am accepting this and moving on to the rest of the performance bottlenecks :D Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues with a purely NumPy method to solve this is that there exists no method to 'slice' a NumPy array using bounds from another over an axis. So the resultant expanded bounds end up becoming a variable-length list of lists such as `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]`. Then you can use `np.eye` and `np.sum` over axis=0 to get the required output.

```
bounds = np.array([[1,2], [1,3], [1,4]])

result = np.stack([np.sum(np.eye(4)[slice(*i)], axis=0) for i in bounds])
print(result)
```

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

I tried various ways of being able to slice the `np.eye(4)` from [start:stop] over a NumPy array of starts and stops but sadly you will need an iteration to accomplish this.

---

**EDIT: Another way you can do this in a vectorized way without any loops is** -

```
def f(b):
    o = np.sum(np.eye(4)[b[0]:b[1]], axis=0)
    return o

np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, bounds)
```

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

**EDIT: If you are looking for a superfast solution but can tolerate a single for loop then the fastest approach based on my simulations among all answers on this thread is** -

```
def h(bounds):
    zz = np.zeros((len(bounds), bounds.max()))

    for z,b in zip(zz,bounds):
        z[b[0]:b[1]]=1
        
    return zz

h(bounds)
```

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: A list comprehension is still a loop. Did you benchmark this? It is much much slower than the loop with slices.

Comment: check my updated answer, without using a list comprehension or explicit for loops

Comment: Still much slower.

Comment: The criteria for the question are not for you to decide though. OPs criteria is not speed but no explicit for loops. Anyways there is a difference of 10 nanoseconds, on my device, in runtime which is nonconsequential w.r.t the scenario in which the question is asked.

Comment: Will check and time with a large matrix, probably tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add that as part of the question if it really is part of the criteria for correct solution for you?

Comment: The question is really open to any approach that is performant on a large data set. My intuition tells me that avoiding context switching and python interpreter during the assignment should improve greatly performance but there is no substitute for profiling the code.

Comment: I benchmarked over 100000 iterations of the above scenario, not large datasets since that was not part of the question. no need to be rude.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a faster approach. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: ITs a great solution, its only slightly slower than using slice()

Answer (score 1):

Using `numba.njit` decorator

```
import numpy as np
import numba
```

---

```
@numba.njit
def numba_assign_in_range(arr, bounds, val):

  for i in range(len(bounds)):

    s, e = bounds[i]
    arr[i, s:e] = val
  
  return arr
```

---

```
test_size = int(1e6) * 2

bounds = np.zeros((test_size, 2), dtype='int32')
bounds[:, 0] = 1
bounds[:, 1] = np.random.randint(0, 100, test_size)

a = np.zeros((test_size, 100))
```

---

with `numba.njit`

```
CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 4 µs
Wall time: 6.2 µs
```

---

without `numba.njit`

```
CPU times: user 3.54 s, sys: 1.63 ms, total: 3.54 s
Wall time: 3.55 s
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but after measuring the performance it turns out to be 4 times slower than looping through the rows

Comment: I will look into this. I left the compilers out for now, but depending on performance it might be a good idea.